# Redirection to custom URL scheme not working

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an Android mobile app with a custom URL scheme like: `mycoolapp://`

I want to redirect users who are sent to a certain page on my website to the mobile app using the URL scheme. I have the following JS code which runs on page load:

```
<script>
window.location = 'mycoolapp://';
</script>
```

This for some reason does nothing.

If I make it as a click, it works. Like this:

```
<button onclick="window.location = 'mycoolapp://';">Open App</button>
```

Or a regular link, works as well:

```
<a href="mycoolapp://">Open App</a>
```

So `onclick`, it works well but `onload`, it doesn't!

I'm testing on Google Chrome

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Any redirects to a custom URI scheme in chrome, that are not triggered by a user click, will result in nothing happening. Everything works fine as long as the user clicks a link/button or if I use a browser that is not chrome (Firefox,...)
Have you managed to find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
window.location.replace("mycoolapp://");
```

This is the equivalent to the header function from PHP.

Comment: Tried it but not working. The PHP header function works well but I need to do this in javascript

Comment: @MichaelSamuel Is jQuery an option for you?
Otherwise use functions:
<script>
function foo() {
    location.href = "mycoolapp://";
}
</script>
<body onload="foo()">

or

<script>
function foo() {
    location.href = "mycoolapp://";
}
addEventListener('load', foo);
</script>

Comment: Still not working. I'm not sure but it seems that this is a new security by Chrome to not open apps like this without the user clicking on a link :(

Comment: @MichaelSamuel I don't think it's a browser-side restriction. When I test with:  <body onload="window.location.replace('//google.com');"> it works fine. Using Chrome Canary.

Comment: @MichaelSamuel Use this instead `window.open('mycoolapp://', '_system')"`   Works well for me.